# Отправка значений всех checkbox в MySQL при нажатии на любой

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

Добрый день всем!
Не хватает знаний в js и php...=(

Есть 2 checkbox с предварительно выставленными значениями:

```
<var>
  <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==1):?>
  <input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked/>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==0):?>
  <input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" value="0"/>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <label for="switch1">Ручное управление</label><br><br> 
</var> 

<var>
  <?php if ($row["PUMP"]==1):?>
  <input id="switch2" class="switch" name="switch2" type="checkbox" checked />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($row["PUMP"]==0):?>
  <input id="switch2" class="switch" name="switch2" type="checkbox" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <label for="switch2">Циркуляционный насос</label><br><br> 
</var>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любой chekbox осуществлялась запись в БД?
Не хватает знаний как правильно сформировать на JS POST запрос при нажатии и разобрать на сервере с помощью PHP по переменным.

Comment: `<?= $row["PUMP"] ? " checked": ""?>` так не пробовали в верстке писать?

Comment: Добавьте в HTML input checkbox атрибут onChange="this.form.submit()"  Прежде нужно checkbox поместить в форму, <form method="POST" action=""> тут ваши checkbox </form>

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, может быть кому-то будет полезно:

```
<body> 
//подключаемся к базе и считываем начальные значения кнопок    
<?php include '.../Check_boil_switchs.php'; ?>

   <form>    
    <var>
      <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==1):?>
      <input  class="switch" name="switch1" id="switch1" type="checkbox" checked/>
      <?php endif; ?>   
      <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==0):?>
      <input  class="switch" name="switch1" id="switch1" type="checkbox"/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <label for="switch1"> ON Ручное управление</label><br><br> 
    </var>  

    <var>
      <?php if ($row["ESP_POWER"]==1):?>
      <input id="switch7" class="switch" name="switch7" type="checkbox" checked/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($row["ESP_POWER"]==0):?>
      <input id="switch7" class="switch" name="switch7" type="checkbox"/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <label for="switch7">ON Питание ESP</label><br><br> 
    </var>

    <var>
      <?php if ($row["HEATER"]==1):?>
      <input  class="switch" name="switch3" id="switch3" type="checkbox" checked/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($row["HEATER"]==0):?>
      <input class="switch" name="switch3" id="switch3"  type="checkbox"/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <label for="switch3">ON ТЭН</label><br><br> 
    </var>  

    <var>
      <?php if ($row["PUMP"]==1):?>
      <input  class="switch" name="switch2" id="switch2" type="checkbox" checked/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($row["PUMP"]==0):?>
      <input  class="switch" name="switch2" id="switch2" type="checkbox"/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <label for="switch2">ON Циркуляционный насос</label><br><br> 
    </var>        

    <var>
      <?php if ($row["SOL_HOT"]==1):?>
      <input id="switch4" class="switch" name="switch4" type="checkbox" checked/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($row["SOL_HOT"]==0):?>
      <input id="switch4" class="switch" name="switch4" type="checkbox"/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <label for="switch4">ON Клапан горячей воды</label><br><br> 
    </var>      

    <var>
      <?php if ($row["SOL_COLD"]==1):?>
      <input id="switch5" class="switch" name="switch5" type="checkbox" checked/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($row["SOL_COLD"]==0):?>
      <input id="switch5" class="switch" name="switch5" type="checkbox"/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <label for="switch5">ON Клапан холодной воды</label><br><br> 
    </var>  

    <var>
      <?php if ($row["HEAT_INPUT_WATER"]==1):?>
      <input id="switch6" class="switch" name="switch6" type="checkbox" checked/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($row["HEAT_INPUT_WATER"]==0):?>
      <input id="switch6" class="switch" name="switch6" type="checkbox"/>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <label for="switch6">ON Система нагрева трубопровода</label><br><br> 
    </var>


    <var>
    <input class="switch" name="Boil_control_switchs" type="checkbox" checked/>       
    </var>


    </form>           

<!--при изменении состояния любого переключателя из "form" сработает этот скрипт-->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(':checkbox').on('change', function()
        {
          //преобразуем данные формы кнопок в строку для отправки запроса на сервер
            var sendData = $("form").serialize();

            $('#results').text(sendData);

            // выводим для проверки как выглядит пакет POST перед отправкой на сервер
            //alert(sendData);
            $.ajax({
                url:  'Write_Switchs.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: sendData,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                 alert(data); //выведет данные, которые пошлет php обработчик в виде echo
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 




</body>
```

PHP обработчик (Write_Switchs.php):

```
<?php
//Распарсим по переменным
if($_POST['switch1']=="on") $Manual_control=1;
else $Manual_control=0;

if($_POST['switch2']=="on") $PUMP=1;
else $PUMP=0;

if($_POST['switch3']=="on") $HEATER=1;
else $HEATER=0;

if($_POST['switch4']=="on") $SOL_HOT=1;
else $SOL_HOT=0;

if($_POST['switch5']=="on") $SOL_COLD=1;
else $SOL_COLD=0;

if($_POST['switch6']=="on") $HEAT_INPUT_WATER=1;
else $HEAT_INPUT_WATER=0;

if($_POST['switch7']=="on") $ESP_POWER=1;
else $ESP_POWER=0;

// проверяем значения переменных
/*
echo $Manual_control;
echo $ESP_POWER;
echo $HEATER;
echo $PUMP;
echo $SOL_HOT;
echo $SOL_COLD; 
echo $HEAT_INPUT_WATER; 
*/ 

//записываем ряд новых значений в базу данных
//---Подключаемся к базе данных--------------------------------------------
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "login", "Pass", "Base_name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Соединение не установлено: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query_switch_now = "INSERT INTO Table_name (Manual_control, ESP_POWER, HEATER, PUMP, SOL_HOT, SOL_COLD, HEAT_INPUT_WATER) VALUES ('".$Manual_control."','".$ESP_POWER."','".$HEATER."','".$PUMP."','".$SOL_HOT."','".$SOL_COLD."','".$HEAT_INPUT_WATER."')"; 


// Записываем актуальные данные в базу
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query_switch_now);

//echo 'Manual_control ='; echo $row["Manual_control"];
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```